# write cache in RAM for NFS?

Tags: nfs, cache, sles

is there a way, solution for a Linux server (SLES) to put write (or even read) caching in RAM?

Having big RAM, ex.: 2 TBytes, but limited NFS IOPS and we need a big IOPS for DB files, stored on NFS.

Comment: I would suggest that you take a look at Db and state there the original issue. instead using a workaround. if you need to use multiple servers then imho mostly a direct Synchronisation between the instance would reduce the number of Iops

Answer (score 4):

Reads are automatically cached both client-size and server-side.

Writes can be cached client-side by mounting the NFS share with the `async` option, at the cost of potentially losing data in case of an unexpected client reboot. Note that important writes, the one done via `sync/fsync()`, are unaffected by this client option (ie: they are guaranteed to be transferred to the server before returning).

Server-side, exporting the share with the `async` option means to discard `fsync()` altogether, which can significantly increase write ops but at the (very real) risk of data corruption if/when an unexpected power loss happens.